# Is it wrong to quit shortly after 2 weeks paid sick leave?

Tags: resignation

I started working somewhere in retail about a month ago. After about 4 days of working there I got covid-19 and was out for 2 weeks. During that time I got paid sick leave(50% of hourly pay). I came back and have worked about 6 days so far. I just got an offer for a job in my field which will pay me about 100% more than I make now. However I feel bad about quitting because they gave me paid sick leave and I'm a new employee there. Is it wrong for me to quit?

Comment: Why don't you include your country? Is sick leave pay not mandatory where you are?

Comment: Is paid sick leave a special bonus your company grants or is it something all companies have to do by law? You may want to add a country tag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Paid sick leave is a benefit that your company granted to you. If you weren't entitled to sick pay then you wouldn't have received it. You didn't receive anything to which you weren't entitled, by the fact of their granting it to you.

If the company was going to let you go, they wouldn't feel bad. This isn't a moral or ethical quandary. You owe them the work that they pay you for. Nothing more or less. They granted a sick pay benefit to you. You owe them nothing in return.

Should you feel bad? I wouldn't.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think about it like that.

Comment: I would only add that whomever hired you there will likely at least momentarily think that you used your sick leave to find a new job which is... shady. Not much they can do about it, besides maybe hold it against you in the future @Bill.

Comment: @Tymoteusz Paul Yeah that's true. That's one of the reasons I feel bad about quitting. It was a coincidence. Like a week into my sick leave I got an email about the job from someone from HR telling me they want to talk to me about the position because I interviewed for another position there a few months ago.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul OP's only been there a month. If they've already gotten a new job in their field then it's much more likely they've been looking since before starting at the retail job. It's not a reasonable assumption that a job search was started in completed in a two week span unless OP's profession is some weird edge case.

Comment: @BSMP there is a difference between just job searching and possibly taking advantage of sick leave to do so. But as I said, nothing they can do about it, just probably leave a bit of bad aftertaste, but that doesn't mean you should ignore a much better offer.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it wrong for me to quit?

No - you took the sick leave and it's accompanying pay in good faith, and retail is almost universally a fairly high-turnover sector and this is for not just a job in your field but a 100% pay increase. Give them the required notice and work it professionally. Don't be a d##k about it during your notice and go enjoy your progression to a more relevant job.

Comment: Thank you!
"Don't be a d##k about it during your notice" I wont. I'm going in tomorrow and I will give them my notice.

Comment: I would add that it might be a good idea to exclude this job from the resume in the future.

Comment: I cordially dissent with Lamplighter.  "This is [just ...] 'business.'  Another day on the retail sales floor."